# php date() numerical description of day

Tags: php

Which is safer/better to use in php to get the numerical number of a day:

```
date('w'); // Numeric representation of the day of the week
```

or

```
date('N'); // From php manual: ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in PHP 5.1.0)
```

I like the second version as it feels more natural but i'm wondering if there are any implications beyond that of using either method?

Comment: And what do you mean by  "safer/better" ?
Stop worrying about such trivial stuff as long as they don't impact what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well, there are two versions for a reason.  There must be implications somewhere down the line of using either of them.  Its this that i dont understand and dont want to blindly accept that i can use either

Comment: The only difference is that one is 0-6 and the other 1-7. Neither is "safer".

Comment: If you care about this at all, consider it a choice of "faith." Anybody offended by the heretic assumption, Sunday is the first day of the week, should use `N`. Those that aren't offended and like their lists to start with zero, use `w`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really trivial, and like the comment said It wont impact your project.

from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

N  - 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)

w  - 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)

The only behavioural difference I can see is that is you did some kind of arithmetic might be altered (like calculating 5 days from Sunday), or array arithmetic (i.e.) arrays are indexed at 0, so if you use 'w' then it can be used to access an element of an array like "Sunday" (or Sunday in another language like Spanish).

Another thing to consider, is that if you use an ISO standard - and the standard changes, like the introduce a new day of the week - then PHP is more likely to update 'N' and deprecate 'w'.

Comment: *"Introduction of new day of the week"* - yeah, I'm thinking you won't have to worry about that *too* much for the time being, especially since you'll probably have to rewrite your application anyway in that case. ;o)

Comment: Yes, there are many more things that could go wrong. If I spent too long thinking about that at work I am not sure my employer would be too happy :P

Comment: +1 for 'introduce a new day of the week'. @deceze beat me to it!

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping someone would get a laugh out of that. :P

Comment: @Dave I'm fine with Mondays, but I'd welcome an additional Sunturday.